# How to use this jQuery codes with .live?

Tags: jquery

I'm using some jQuery effects on my images. But when i click load more button, don't working JQuery next images. Problem is Dom ready. So, i want to use my jQuery codes with .live but i don't know how to use .live

Please help me, thank you.

1:

```
     var hoverImg = '<div class="hoverimg"></div>';

$(".thumb").each(function(){
    $(this).children("div").each(function(){
        $(this).find("a").append(hoverImg);
    });
});

$(".thumb div").hover(function() {
    $(this).find(".hoverimg").animate({ opacity: 'toggle' });
});

$(".thumb").hover(function() {
    $(this).find("div").each(function(){
        $(this).find(".shadow").fadeOut(500);
    });
});
```

2:

```
var shadowImg = '<div class="shadow"></div>';

$(".thumb").each(function(){
    $(this).children("div").each(function(){
        $(this).append(shadowImg);
    });
});
```

3:

```
var c = '';
var d = '';
$('.view-content div.views-row').each(function(){
    c = 0;
    d = 0;
    var i = 1;
    d = $(this).find('.thumbimg').length;
    $(this).find('.thumbimg').each(function(){
        sayi=i++;
        $(this).append('<div class="img_no">0'+sayi+'</div>');
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

As of jQuery 1.7, the .live() method is deprecated. Use .on() to attach event handlers.

The way it works is like this:

```
$('#select_something_static').on("click", ".something_dynamic", {'anydata':True}, handler);
```

You call "on" on a static top level element of DOM (ascendant of dynamic nodes) and then select dynamic nodes. When event triggers on ascendant, jquery searches for selector (".something_dynamic" in my case), and if it was triggered there, calls handler and puts data ({'anydata':True} in my case) in event.data

Comment: Thank you but still have a problem. Can you apply .live on my codes, please?

Answer (score 0):

Use `on()` instead.

1.

```
$(".thumb div").on("hover", function() {
    $(this).find(".hoverimg").animate({ opacity: 'toggle' });
});

$(".thumb").on("hover", function() {
    $(this).find("div").each(function(){
        $(this).find(".shadow").fadeOut(500);
    });
});
```

Comment: Thank you but still have a problem. Can you apply .live on my codes, please?